# Custom tag's support when migrated from Struts 1 to Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, migration, struts-1

There is a project developed in Struts 1 to be migrated to Struts 2.

**Problem is:**

The application has a lot of custom tags were written using Struts 1. So when migrating to Struts 2 is there a way that I can keep those custom tag support for existing JSPs.

But we suppose to remove all the Struts 1.x related jars when migrating to Struts 2, so rewriting those custom tags with Struts 2 is a huge effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are using Struts1 and you remove it, then you should remove tags dependent on it. However, you can use any other taglibs, including [JSTL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Can+we+use+JSTL+with+the+framework) corresponding to your JSP specification version.

Comment: Thanks Roman for the answer. Ok the situation is like this. Current application has developed lot of custom tags using stuts 1. So when migrate as you mentioned i have to remove those tags depend on struts 1 which is a huge effort. Any way since it has to be some how migrated what i thought of doing is rewrite those struts 1 written tag using struts 2 custom tags so that i dont have to touch any of current jsp's. Please advice whether its the correct approach? Thank you

Comment: If you write your custom tags, who will support them? If you make an effort to write your own custom tags and it happens they will work for you, you stick with the version of Struts. The same thing happened with Dojo tags. So, Struts 1 tags should be replaced.